# Does the 5G User Plane Function (UPF) supports multiple network slices? And if so how does it ensure the Qos?

Tags: 5g

Exploring 5G Network Slicing and read that NSSF is the function that controls the Network slicing in a 5g infrastructure. Pair of SMF and UPF, works for slicing.

But I am not clear about whether UPF supports only one slice or can support more. What are the information exchanged between UPF and SMF regarding network slicing.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes @phuzi. I Am trying to develop UPF Network Function in C language. For implementing Network Slicing I don't have a solid understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the User Plane Function (UPF) has the capability to support various Network Slices (NW slices). In order to achieve this, the Session Management Function (SMF) includes the S-NSSAI (Single Network Slice Selection Assistance Information Element) as an optional component in the PFCP (Packet Forwarding Control Protocol) establishment Request.

For more detailed information, I would recommend referring to specification 29.244, specifically section 7.5.2 titled "PFCP Session Establishment Request."